# The "inverse" of the Markov property: conditioning on the future rather than the past

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-analysis

Given a probability space, we say that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is Markov w.r.t its own filtration $(\mathcal F_t)$ if for all $s<t$,

$$ P(X_t \in \cdot | \mathcal F_s) = P(X_t \in \cdot | X_s)$$

Let $\mathcal G_t = \mathcal F_\infty \setminus \mathcal F_t $. What is the name of the processes that satisfy

$$ P(X_s \in \cdot | \mathcal G_t) = P(X_s \in \cdot | X_t)$$ for $s<t$ ? What is their relationship with Markov processes ? Can you give a non-trivial example of such process ?

Comment: That is simply a Markov process with a reparametrisation. Mathematically the terms "future" and "past" hold no meaning at all. So this is just a slightly unconventionally parametrized Markov process.

Comment: @Lazy Could you show the equivalence ?

Comment: I suppose $\mathcal G_t$ is supposed to denote the $\sigma$-Algebra created by all $X_s$ with $s\geq t$ (the set difference does not really make sense there). Then $\mathcal G_t$ defines a filtration with the reversed real order. Next note that $t\geq0$ is not nescessary for the definition of markov processes, instead you have $t\in T$ where $T$ is some totally ordered set. So this way just by reversing order you’ll see that you again achieve the markov property.

Answer (score 1):

If, rather, $\mathcal G_t:=\sigma(X_s: s\ge t)$, then the Markov property as you have stated it is equivalent to the symmetrical relationship
$$
P(X_u\in B\mid \mathcal G_t)=P(X_u\in B\mid X_t)
$$
for $u<t$. Each is in turn equivalent to the conditional independence of $\mathcal F_t$ and $\mathcal G_t$, given $\sigma(X_t)$, for each $t$.

Comment: Given the definition of Markov process that I gave, can you prove rigorously the equivalence ? Your definition of $(\mathcal G_t)$ is correct.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4743554/is-the-markov-property-equivalent-to-the-statement-past-and-future-and-independ.