# About the « Past is independent from the future given the present » statement

Tags: probability, markov-process

This question arises from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4743554/863176), and more generally from many textbook asserting that *« for any stochastic process having the Markov property, the past and the future are independent given the present. »*

Let $X = \{X(t) : t\in \left[0, \infty\right) \}$ be a stochastic process, and suppose that $X$ has the Markov property, *i.e.* for all $s, t \in \left[0, \infty\right)$ s.t. $s<t$, we have $$ \mathbb{P}(X(t) \in \cdot | F_s) = \mathbb{P}(X(t) \in \cdot | X(s)) .$$

In the other hand, we say of a stochastic process $S = \{S(t) : t\in\left[0,\infty\right)\}$ that *the past is independent from the future given the present* if the relation $$ \mathbb{E}\left[S(t_1)S(t_3) | S(t_2)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[S(t_1)|S(t_2)\right] \mathbb{E}\left[S(t_3)|S(t_2)\right] $$

holds as long as $0\leq t_1 < t_2 < t_3$.

The question is: how do you show that the past is independent from the future given the present for $X$? I tried to write $\mathbb{P}(X(t) \in \cdot | X(s))$ as an expectation, but to no avail.

Comment: What you have in the last equation is more like „the past is uncorrelated from the future conditional on the present“.